# Filtering an object that contains a map in the field and searching for keys in the map that match at least one key from the provided collection

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have a collection that I sorted by the field that contains the time.

```java
collectsPublishEntityActual
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(PublishListEntity::getInstant)
                        .reversed())
                .filter(publishListEntity -> publishListEntity.getUrlsBundles()
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(k -> k.getKey().equals()) ?????????
                )
....
```

```java
public class PublishListEntity implements Serializable {

    private Map<PackId, String> urlsPack;

    private Instant instant;
```

```java
   class PackId implements Serializable {
        private String field1;
        private String field2;
    }
```

I also have a collection of keys, the key is an object that consists of 2 string fields("F", "1").

```java
Set<PackId> packIds ;
```

I need to find the entity where the map contains the keys provided in **Set packIds**.

I find it difficult to perform filtering, I need to get only one from the collection of entities, the very first one, which will contain a map in the field that contains at least one key from
The **Set** packIds provided as keys.

Comment: I suggest using `sorted` *after* `filter`.

Comment: Why? I mean .What will it give?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by any key of set exist in Map using `anyMatch` and get first one by `findFirst`

```
collectsPublishEntityActual
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(PublishListEntity::getInstant)
                        .reversed())
                .filter(publishListEntity -> packIds
                        .stream()
                        .anyMatch(k -> publishListEntity.getUrlsBundles().containsKey(k)))
                .findFirst();
            .
```